# Passing a string into a function after performing malloc

Tags: c

This is the code I have in my main C function.

```
char *filename;            

filename = malloc(2001); //if I don't do this step it gives me an error

filename = ListDirectoryContents("test_data\\tmp");//this returns a string  for filename

printf("filename : %s ", filename);//value of filename is displayed which is an address and is NOT NULL OR EMPTY

copyObjectFileInINfolder(filename, logger);//here I am passing the filename to this function where I am getting the error
```

Ok now what I am trying to do is I am trying to pass the string filename into the function (in the function the variable for filename is object)

```
void copyObjectFileInINfolder(char *object, char* logger2);
{
        char source[500];
        char destination[500];
        char cmd[1000];
        printf("\nobject : 123%s123\n", object);//Here the out put I see is "object : 123123"
        printf("\nlogger : %s\n", logger2);

         if(flag ==2)//for windows
         {      
                  //object +=14;
                  printf("\nobject : %s\n", object););//Here the out put I see is "object : "

                  sprintf(source, "test_data\\tmp\\%s", object ); //full address of source file
                  sprintf(destination, "..\\in\\%s", object ); //full address of where the file is to be copied


                  sprintf(cmd,"IF EXIST %s del /Q %s", destination, destination);//to make sure to delete the file if it already exists in the safeXhonw\in folder
                  system(cmd);
                  memset(cmd,0,strlen(cmd));//deleting old values stored in cmd

                  sprintf(cmd, "copy %s %s", source, destination );
         }

        system(cmd);//using linux terminal or Windows command prompt to copy file from source folder into safeXhomedirectory in folder             

        memset(cmd,0,strlen(cmd));//deleting old values stored in cmd

        memset(source,0,strlen(source));//deleting old values stored in source
        memset(destination,0,strlen(destination));//deleting old values stored in destination

}
```

But when I pass it, it is always empty, i.e. filename/object does not show any value, not even " (null)". I know it might be something to do with this malloc command.

HERE IS the other function

```
char* ListDirectoryContents(const char *sDir)
{
WIN32_FIND_DATA fdFile;
HANDLE hFind = NULL;

char sPath[2000];

//Specify a file mask. *.* = We want everything!
sprintf(sPath, "%s\\*.*", sDir);

if((hFind = FindFirstFile(sPath, &fdFile)) == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
{
    printf("Path not found: [%s]\n", sDir);
    return 1;
}

do
{
    //Find first file will always return "."
    //    and ".." as the first two directories.
    if(strcmp(fdFile.cFileName, ".") != 0
            && strcmp(fdFile.cFileName, "..") != 0)
    {
        //Build up our file path using the passed in
        //  [sDir] and the file/foldername we just found:
        sprintf(sPath, "%s\\%s", sDir, fdFile.cFileName);

        //Is the entity a File or Folder?
        if(fdFile.dwFileAttributes &FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY)
        {
            printf("Directory: %s\n", sPath);
            ListDirectoryContents(sPath); //Recursion, I love it!
        }
        else{
            printf("File: %s\n", sPath);
            FindClose(hFind);
            return sPath;
        }
    }
   }while(FindNextFile(hFind, &fdFile)); //Find the next file.

FindClose(hFind); //Always, Always, clean things up!

    return "";
}
```

Comment: I'm almost sure you're overwriting the `malloc()`-ed memory.

Comment: @SouravGhosh how to solve this?

Comment: Show us `ListDirectoryContents()`.

Comment: `filename = malloc(2001); filename = ListDirectoryContents("test_data\\tmp");` makes no sense. Malloc is useless here. If it gives you error when you remove the first line, then you have undefined behavior somewhere.

Comment: @SouravGhosh I have added ListDirectoryContents().

Comment: Yup - what you are doing is inherently borken.

Comment: @ALL I know something is wrong that is why I posted it.

Comment: all you got is `return "";`

Comment: no return ""; is only possible when there are no files in the folder, which there are, but the char *filenames before I pass it to the function shows me a valid file name.

Comment: 'return sPath' - returns local array :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have *two* problems: The first is pretty obvious, and that's the reassignment of `filename` making you lose the original pointer.

The other problem is that in the `ListDirectoryContents` function you return a pointer to the local variable `sPath`, which will lead to *undefined behavior* because once the function returns the variable doesn't exist any more.

I can see two possible solutions:

1. Pass the `filename` as a second argument to the `ListDirectoryContents` function, and use that argument instead of `sPath`.
2. Don't allocate memory for `filename`, instead allocate `sPath` dynamically in the `ListDirectoryContents` function.

---

Also, no matter what you do to your problems, the common thing to do when a function fails somehow is not to return a pointer to a valid, but empty, string. Instead one usually returns `NULL`.

Oh by the way, the recursion in `ListDirectoryContents` won't really work as you expect, as you don't handle the returned value, you just discard it.

Comment: I would go with (2), on the grounds that the caller has no idea how much space is needed, (that, and comment/doc to emphasize that the caller assumes responsibility for result lifetime).

Comment: In fact, this almost demands returning some more complex 'list' struct.